# Subarray of ints summing to target number negative values

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, math, sub-array

Referencing https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-subarray-with-given-sum-in-array-of-integers/ for some reason I'm feeling a little thick about this and not totally grasping the reason that once you find the highest index for (current_sum - target_sum) in the map, that you know if you start at the index immediately following that in the array and include the values up to the current index where you encounter this in the array, that you have your subarray solution.

I pretty much get it, that it's because if we've reached a point in our iterating of the array that we've seen the difference between our current sum and the target number, then if we remove that difference from the sum we have found the subarray for the solution, but I can't quite grasp why exactly that is. For example, what if the difference is "2" but the index we have stored in our map where we last saw the sum was "2" is not immediately before the subarray leading up to where we are now and provides the solution. Again, I kind of get it but would appreciate a clear and precise explanation so I have that "aha" moment and more solidly grasp it.

Also wondering the logic that might lead me to this solution after solving this in a different way for positive integers only, namely the efficient solution covered here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-subarray-with-given-sum/.

Thanks.

```java
public static void subArraySum(int[] arr, int n, int sum) { 
        //cur_sum to keep track of cummulative sum till that point 
        int cur_sum = 0; 
        int start = 0; 
        int end = -1; 
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>(); 

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
            cur_sum = cur_sum + arr[i]; 
            //check whether cur_sum - sum = 0, if 0 it means 
            //the sub array is starting from index 0- so stop 
            if (cur_sum - sum == 0) { 
                start = 0; 
                end = i; 
                break; 
            } 
            //if hashMap already has the value, means we already  
            // have subarray with the sum - so stop 
            if (hashMap.containsKey(cur_sum - sum)) { 
                start = hashMap.get(cur_sum - sum) + 1; 
                end = i; 
                break; 
            } 
            //if value is not present then add to hashmap 
            hashMap.put(cur_sum, i); 

        } 
        // if end is -1 : means we have reached end without the sum 
        if (end == -1) { 
            System.out.println("No subarray with given sum exists"); 
        } else { 
            System.out.println("Sum found between indexes " 
                            + start + " to " + end); 
        } 

    }
```

Comment: I see you've done a lot of work on the problem already and that's great. It might help others to work through a specific case and show how the result differs from what you expected -- that's much easier for others to understand than a program that just doesn't work. A couple of other comments. You mention a solution that works for positive integers. Given a list of positive and negative integers, can you change the problem so that you can apply the positives-only solution? Also, this problem might be an example of 0-1 assignment or another form of constrained optimization -- search for that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! Sorry if it wasn't clear, but that is the solution provided on the site I linked to. I've verified it's correct, and I didn't have expectations of how to do it differently, I'm just not totally confident I understand why it works. If I'm following your question about applying the positive only solution or tweaking it to work for negative numbers, I see no easy way to do that. So I don't disagree this solution is a good one, just looking for better understanding of it. I will look up 0-1 assignment and constrained optimization. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, I'm thinking about something like this. Suppose the most negative numbers is -42. If you add, say, 100, to every number, then they're all positive, and it seems like the sum of the numbers is changed by a multiple of 100. If you add a multiple of 100 (let's say n times 100, where n is an integer) to the target value, can you find a combination of n values which add up to target plus n times 100? If so then you have a solution for the original problem. I've left out the question of dealing with n -- maybe some values of n work and some don't. I haven't thought it through, maybe you can.